# Interface for I/O library

Tags: c, interface, io, conventions

When someone wants to build a C library for dealing with I/O (dealing with a specific file format), they pretty much have to provide the following:

```
/* usual opaque struct setup */
struct my_context;
typedef struct my_context my_context_t;

/* Open context for reading from user specified callbacks */
my_context_t* my_open_callback(void* userdata,
    size_t(*read_cb)(void* data, size_t size, size_t count, void* userdata),
    int(*close_cb)(void* userdata),
    void(*error_cb)(const char* error_msg)
    );
```

And then later provide some common ones:

```
/* Open directly from file */
my_context_t* my_open_file(const char * filename);

/* Open from an existing memory block */
my_context_t* my_open_memory(const char* buf, size_t len);
```

As far as as understand there are possibly others, but is this one considered to reduce inconsistencies, unsafe practices and inefficiencies in the design, or is there something else considered best practice ? Is there a name for this convention/best practice ?

Comment: What you show is not in any way a "standard" way of creating an API for file I/O. It is *one* possible way to do it, but it's not the only way. So to answer your question: No, there's no "reference" interface.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that what you present doesn't appear to provide anything like what I would want for an API focused on a particular file format, unless that format were merely a vehicle for raw byte streams.  Such formats exist, but what I usually think of when I hear "file format" is much more structured and application-specific.

Comment: Best practice? It all depends, this is certainly common and not unreasonable pattern. Generally a more convenient and flexible basic interface for the _caller_ end is to invert the callbacks by having the application feed data into a progressive parser. Of course the trade-off between complexity at the caller and callee ends rather depends on how many of the latter you expect to have. A minor pet peeve of mine is the overuse of function pointers. Consider declaring a `my_read_cb` function and having to be implemented at the caller end, which may do further routing from there when if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

These are interface design questions. A good interface provides a useful abstraction and hides implementation details. In your example, `my_context_t` elides some of the implementation details from your user base, provided you don't fully define the type in a public header. This provides you with the freedom to make substantial changes to your implementation without forcing your entire user base to rewrite their code. It is a very good practice, provided the rest of your abstraction is a good fit to the problem space. Sometimes you just have to commit to exposing additional detail at the interface level.